# Nodejs: Can't post a string filed and image on the same request with Express and Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am using mutler to upload image with post request and also string data.
When I upload only the image with Postman or React, it is working, but when I send also the strings, it shows this:

```
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
```

The string got saved to MySQL but not the image.

**That's my code for the Multer:**

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, './public/images/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        const mimeExtension = {
            'image/jpeg': '.jpeg',
            'image/jpg': '.jpg',
            'image/png': '.png',
            'image/gif': '.gif',
        }
        callBack(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, callBack) => {
        // console.log(file.mimetype)
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||
            file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
            file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
            file.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
            callBack(null, true);
        } else {
            callBack(null, false);
            req.fileError = 'File format is not valid';
        }
    }
});
```

**And that's my post request:**

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
   try {

       if (!req.file) {
           console.log("You didnt upload a picture for your project");
       } 
        
       const { title, about_the_project, project_link, user_id } = req.body

       const projectnum = await SQL(`INSERT into project(title,about_the_project,project_link,user_id)
       VALUES('${title}','${about_the_project}','${project_link}',${user_id}) `)
       console.log(projectnum.insertId);

       console.log(req.file && req.file.filename)
       let imagesrc = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/images/' + req.file && req.file.filename

       await SQL(`UPDATE project SET image = '${imagesrc}' WHERE projectid = ${projectnum.insertId}`)

       res.send({ msg: "You add a new project" })

   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return res.sendStatus(500)
   }

})
```

**On React that's the code:**

```
const PostNewProject = async () => {

    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('image', imgsrc)

    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/project`, {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, about_the_project, project_link, languages, user_id }),formData,
      // credentials: "include"
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    if (data.err) {
      document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = data.err
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = data.msg
    }

  }
```

**And the input for the image upload**

```
<Input
  type='file'
  name='image'
  sx={{ width: '25ch' }}
  onChange={(e) => setImgsrc(e.target.files[0])}
/>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You did not write a comma after the filename and before the callback function in the Multer.
I think you should check you exports too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).